# Pin UITableView above Interactive Input Accessory View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, inputaccessoryview

I have an `inputAccessoryView` and a `UITableView` above it, similar to that of the Messages app. The `keyboardDismiss` mode of the table view is interactive. I've been trying to work out how to add a constraint to the tableview to have it always positioned above the input accessory view, even whilst dragging the keyboard down. However I haven't found a way to do it (since they're not in the same "View"). Has anyone found a way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean that you append an input accessory view to the keyboard? If so, that value is returned as part of the keyboard's size in the keyboard notification methods. You can use that to set the `UITableView` frame or content offset.

Comment: @mbm29414 Yeah that's right. But the input accessory view is interactive so you can drag to dismiss the keyboard. I can't find a way to drag the keyboard and make the tableview follow the keyboard down.

Comment: Ok, but that's not really what you're asking in your question.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this one?

Comment: @Tometoyou This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ky7YRh01by8&t=1142s) tutorial is the answer to your question.